# NESASM - Inline method jump

Tags: assembly, methods

Is it possible to make inline 'method' jump in nesasm (or any asm it may work in nesasm)?

What I mean is:
I got code like this.

```
Start;
    LDA $0000
    ; here goes more code
    JSR SomeMethod ; jump to method (put back pointer on stack)
EndOfMethod: ; just help label to make code more clear
    STA $0000
    ; here goes a lot of more code
SomeMethod:
    TAX
    ;here goes more method code
    RTS ; return to position on stack
```

And now I want to make 'SomeMethod' inline (like in C++) so when compiled it will look like this:

```
Start;
    LDA $0000
    ; here goes more code
SomeMethod:
    TAX
    ;here goes more method code
EndOfMethod: ; just help label to make code more clear
    STA $0000
    ; here goes a lot of more code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assembler supports some kind of macro, particularly one w/ parameters, then you could define `SomeMethod` as a macro and use a parameter to have each instance have its own set of labels (by incorporating the parameter in the label name).

Something like:

```
defMacro SomeMethodMacro(idx):
SomeMethod$idx:
    TAX
    ;code...
EndOfMethod$idx:
endMacro
```

And then when you want to stick an instance in your code:

```
SomeMethodMacro(001)
```

where you'd be responsible for insuring each instance has a different argument.

Comment: Thx, now I know what am I searching for, and found it :)

Answer (score 0):

No, in assembly language *you* are the compiler. You have complete control over all instructions used, but also get all the responsibility.

The assembler just translates the instructions from a text file to binary instructions.